# Determining if a relation is reflexive

Tags: python, set

A binary relation \$R\$ on a set \$A\$ is called reflexive if and only if \$R(a, a)\$ for every element \$a \in A\$.

I want to know if there can be any improvements made on the function below to make it more efficient.

```
def reflexive(R):
    '''
    @param R : set containing homogenous elements
    '''
    result = []
    a = []
    y = []

    for a1, a2 in R:
        if (a1 == a2):
            result.append((a1,a2))
            y.append(a1)

        if (a1 not in a):
            a.append(a1) #contains list of a0

    if (set(a) == set(y)):
        print("Reflexive")
        return (result, True)

    print("Not Reflexive")
    return ([] , False)
```

Test case:

```
R2 = reflexive([(1, 3), (1, 5), (3, 1), (3, 5), (7, 5)])

Not Reflexive
[]
```

Comment: `reflexive([(1, 1), (1, 2)])` prints "Reflexive". I would consider this a bug, since the input implies that the number 2 is an element of A and is not related to itself.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I believe that that is the intended behaviour, if you consider that the set _A_ is {1}.

Comment: @200_success But then, how would I be able to use the function if I wanted to consider the sets {1, 2}, or {1, 2, 3}, where still only (1, 1) and (1, 2) were related?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It is pretty weird, though, that `reflexive([(1,1), (2,2), (1,3)])` is `True`, but `reflexive([(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)])` is `False`. I think you are right that there is a fundamental problem with the function.

Comment: @200_success That is exactly what I tried out after reading your docstring, but hesitated to post a comment, because I think I haven't understood it well enough ;)

Comment: @Joseph You need more test cases. With only this one test case, `return False, []` is the simplest solution.

Comment: @RolandIllig, I agree. However I am thinking about converting this function to a matrix. It seems to be easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Performance

It takes a very long time to conclude that `reflexive((a, a) for a in range(100000))` is true.  The main culprit is

> ```
> if (a1 not in a):
> ```

Since `a` is a list, the `not in` test involves a linear scan, such that your entire function is \$\Omega(\left|R\right|^2)\$.  Ideally, it should be \$O(\left|R\right|)\$.

### Interface

The docstring is insufficient to describe what the function does.  In addition to a better description, I recommend adding [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

A function like this shouldn't print anything as a side-effect.

It would be more conventional to return `True`/`False` as the *first* element of the result rather than the second.

I don't think that there is any benefit to returning an ordered list; a `set` would be more appropriate.

### Suggested solution

I'd write it this way, taking advantage of generator expressions to make it shorter.

```
def reflexive(R):
    """
    Determine whether the binary relation R on a set A is reflexive, and if so,
    which elements of R are essential for it to be reflexive.

    R is an iterable of homogeneous pairs.

    >>> reflexive([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])
    (False, set())

    >>> is_reflexive, essential = reflexive([(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1)])
    >>> is_reflexive
    True
    >>> essential == {(1, 1), (2, 2)}
    True

    >>> reflexive((a, a) for a in range(100000))[0]
    True
    """
    R = list(R)
    A = set(a for a, _ in R)
    result = set(ab for ab in R if ab[0] == ab[1])
    return (True, result) if len(A) == len(result) else (False, set())
```

Comment: Wow. This is clean! I got a long way to go

Comment: Also, I didn't even notice that checking if an element is in the list was of O(n) time, like you said effectively making it O(n^2)

Comment: what is this Ohm-notation?

Comment: @cat [Big-Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) is a stricter statement than Big-O. (Side note: I find "Big Omega" to be a funny name, since "omega" itself means "big O" in Greek.)

Comment: @cat That's part of Big-O-Notation with \$f = \Omega(g)\$ meaning \$f \ge g\$ asymptotically (i.e. the inequality of \$\mathscr O\$ reversed)

Comment: @200_success I wouldn't call one stricter than the other. They are just counterparts. The "strict" one would be \$\Theta\$. It all depends in what bound you're interesed in whether you need \$\le\$ or \$\ge\$

Comment: Why not write as `result = set((a, b) for a, b in R if a == b)`

Answer (score 10):

Regardless of whether the function is actually correct or not, there are some issues that could be improved:

1. I would expect a function that is supposed to determine whether a relation \$R\$ over a set \$A\$ is reflexive to take two arguments:

   - The relation \$R\$,
   - and the set \$A\$.

   Providing only the set \$\{(a, b) | a, b \in A, R(a,b)\}\$ and deducing \$A\$ from it is insufficient, because there could be elements in \$A\$ which are not related to any other element. This could lead to a false positive result.
2. I would expect the function to only return a boolean value, and to have no side effects like printing its result. Leave that to the caller.
3. The docstring of the function does not explain well enough what it expects as its argument, and does not explain at all what the function does.
4. `a` and `y` are poorly named. What is their meaning?
5. Instead of creating `a` and `y` a as lists to which is `append`ed (needlessly checking if elements are already contained), only to convert them to sets at the end, why don't you just create them as sets in the first place and `add` to them?
6. Parentheses are not needed around conditions in `if` statements:

   ```
   if a1 == a2:
   if a1 not in a:
   if set(a) == set(y):
   ```

   (also technically not around the returned tuples)

   ```
   return result, True
   return [], False
   ```
7. This comment confuses me: What is `a0`?

   ```
   if (a1 not in a):
       a.append(a1) #contains list of a0
   ```

   You better just remove the comment.